# Cytoscape - AOP Xplorer Interaction

Tags: aop, cytoscape

I am very new at this area. I am trying to be a toxicologist and write my Ph.D thesis on hERG inhibition and long QT syndrome. I have a lot of data in terms of literature and shaped it in my mind regarding how to visualize it as an AOP. However, when it comes to do it, my lecturer recommended me to use AOP Xplorer but I couldn't understand how to do it.

Is it possible to visualize my own AOP with regards to my topic via AOP Xplorer (I think so but I need some documents & training to understand it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should be able to visualize your own AOP using AOP Xplorer.  If you go to: https://github.com/DataSciBurgoon/aop_networks they have a number of sample networks (look for .sif files).  If you construct your data similarly, you should be able to read it in.  I've never used that app, however, so your mileage may vary...